# SQL запрос на дату

Tags: delphi

Доброй ночи всем.

Возникла такая проблема в написании запросов я особо не силен, так что сам пытался.
Код

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;

  stDay : array[1..7] of string[11] = ('воскресенье', 'понедельник', 'вторник', 'среда', 'четверг', 'пятница', 'суббота');
  stMonth : array[1..12] of string[8] = ('января', 'февраля', 'марта', 'апреля', 'мая', 'июня', 'июля', 'августа', 'сентября', 'октября', 'ноября', 'декабря');

implementation
{$R *.dfm}
uses DateUtils;
```

Вот код запроса.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    st : string;
begin
    st:= FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy',Now);
    Form1.Query1.SQL[3] := '(ECPsrok = '''+st+''')';
    Form1.Query1.Open;
    if form1.Query1.RecordCount <> 0 then
        form1.DataSource1.DataSet := Form1.Query1
    else begin
        ShowMessage('На сегодня ничего нет.');
        //form1.DataSource1.DataSet := Table1;
    end;
end;
```

В query прописано

```
SELECT *
FROM po.db
```

Скажу честно, код увидел в интернете, решил попробовать написать программу с использованием этого запроса. Но при нажатии на кнопку выбивает этакое сообщение

> `Project Project.exe raised exceptoin class EStringListError with message 'List index out if bounds(3)'.Process stop....`

Подскажите, в чем может быть ошибка. Заранее спс. Забыл сказать что создавал базу в DBD Типа Paradox.

Comment: Да вы все что, издеваетесь?..

@Paul, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 1):

```
TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); 
var st : string; 
begin st:= FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy',Now); 
Form1.Query1.SQL.Clear;
Form1.Query1.sql.text:='select * from po.db';// Если без фильтра
// Если надо фильтр
// Form1.Query1.sql.text:='select * from po.db where myday=''+st+'';
Form1.Query1.Open; 
if form1.Query1.RecordCount <> 0 then form1.DataSource1.DataSet := Form1.Query1 
else 
begin ShowMessage('На сегодня ничего нет.'); 
end;
```

PS:строку **po.db** проверьте, с access'ом давно уже не работал.

Comment: Уважаемы Vfvtnjd, а кто вам сказал, что с Access вообще вопрос?

Comment: Незнаю, почему то прочитал как аксес. Херь знает..

Answer (score -1):

Есть способ использовать переменную. Например, ваш запрос на выборку

```
select * from doc where ddate1=:ValueDate1

Form1.Query1.SQL.text:='select * from doc where ddate1=:ValueDate1';
Form1.Query1.params[0]:=now-1; // текущий момент - 1 день 
Form1.Query1.open;
```

Или напрямую отредактировать запрос

```
Function Q(s:string):string; // моя функция для возврата строки в кавычках
begin
  result:='"'+s+'"';
end;

s:=q(DateTimeToStr(now-1));
Form1.Query1.SQL.text:='select * from doc where ddate1='+s;
Form1.Query1.open;
```

Небольшой [пример](http://netsoftware.ucoz.ru/news/avtomatizacija_rabochego_mesta/2011-09-12-8) программы работы с Access + Delphi, там же контакты - если что проконсультирую.

P.S. тут капча реально зверская.